# async programming in portable library

Tags: .net, async-await, portable-class-library

I'm very confused about the new async stuff.  I have a portable library implementing my model with some classes with virtual functions I hope to use in ASP .NET, WPF, Windows Store, Silverlight 5, and Windows Phone 8.  They might target WCF functionality, CSharp SQLite, or be overridden in platform-specific libraries for local file stuff.

How do I set it up now that synchronous programming is frowned upon in the Windows Store world?  I tried adding async keywords and so forth in the portable library for the virtual functions, but it says that I don't have the necessary frameworks.  How can I reuse this library without rewriting it?  Is OOP programming totally dead now?

Comment: What is OOB programming? Is that a poor man's version of OOP?

Comment: Anyway, the new async way doesn't change anything; you can still use your library as-is, especially if none of the calls take longer than 50 ms.  That's Microsoft's metric, and only 10% of all calls in their framework meet that metric and are therefore written to be asynchronous. The remaining 90% are still good ole ordinary synchronous methods.

Comment: Sorry, I meant OOP.  The brain is pretty fried after 15 hours of programming.

Comment: To expand, I was happy before using a Thread to do the operation, and then (for Silverlight and WP) using Dispatch.  What's the equivalent in Windows Store that doesn't break the performance?  For example, say I have an event handler for a button click, is there a lambda expression I can use that will call the function that takes a long time, but still return from the event handler right away?

Answer (score 2):

VS will happily allow `async` in portable libraries targeting .NET 4.5 and Windows Store. If you need other platforms (notably .NET 4.0 and Silverlight 5) then you need to install [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

If you need a reference, the [source for my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest) is available; the core assembly is a portable library that depends on Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm addressing it is to use a helper class I adapted from a previous version.  Basically:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace JTModelsWinStore.Local
{
    public delegate void UseDataDelegate(DataCoordinator data);
    public delegate bool GetDataDelegate(DataCoordinator data);

    public class DataCoordinator
    {
        public DependencyObject Consumer;
        public GetDataDelegate GetDataFunction;
        public UseDataDelegate UseDataFunction;
        public bool GetDataSucceeded;
        public Exception ErrorException;
        public string ErrorMessage;

        public DataCoordinator(
            DependencyObject consumer,
            GetDataDelegate getDataFunction,
            UseDataDelegate useDataFunction)
        {
            Consumer = consumer;
            GetDataFunction = getDataFunction;
            UseDataFunction = useDataFunction;
            GetDataSucceeded = false;
            ErrorException = null;
            ErrorMessage = null;
        }

        public Task GetDataAsync()
        {
            GetDataSucceeded = false;

            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                if (GetDataFunction != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        GetDataSucceeded = GetDataFunction(this);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        GetDataSucceeded = false;
                        ErrorException = exception;
                        ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
                    }
                }

                if (UseDataFunction != null)
                {
                    if (Consumer != null)
                    {
                        var ignored = Consumer.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                        {
                            UseDataFunction(this);
                        });
                    }
                    else
                        UseDataFunction(this);
                }
            });
            return task;
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the Windows store code:

```
private async void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    DataCoordinator data = new DataCoordinator(this, Logon, LogonCompleted);
    await data.GetDataAsync();
}

private bool Logon(DataCoordinator data)
{
    LoggedOnUserID = ServiceClient.LogOn(UserName, Password);

    if (LoggedOnUserID == null)
    {
        UserName = "AnonymousUser";
        Password = "";

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ServiceClient.ErrorMessage))
            data.ErrorMessage = "Log on failed.";

        return false;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ServiceClient.ErrorMessage))
    {
        data.ErrorMessage = ServiceClient.ErrorMessage;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private void LogonCompleted(DataCoordinator data)
{
    if (data.GetDataSucceeded && LoggedOnUserID != null)
        pageTitle.Text = "Logged On";
    else
        pageTitle.Text = "LogOn Failed";
}
```

I provide the helper with two functions, one for getting the data (slow), and one for doing something with the data in the UI.  I know I could do it in two nested lambdas, but I like hiding the two lambdas, which is more comfortable for an old-timer like me.

Please do feel free to critique it, for others' benefit as well as my own.